# Binding a struct property on a ViewModel to a WPF toolkit PropertyGrid does not update ViewModel when UI values change

Tags: wpf, mvvm, data-binding, wpftoolkit, reactiveui

I am trying to use a WPF Toolkit PropertyGrid to display properties on a ViewModel in ReactiveUI. Because of Reasons™, one of these properties is a custom Size struct:

**Size.cs**

```
public struct Size
{
    public float Width { get; set; }
    public float Height { get; set; }
}
```

Which my ViewModel exposes:

**ElementViewModel.cs**

```
public class ElementViewModel : ReactiveObject
{
    private Size _size;
    public Size Size
    {
        get => _size;
        set => this.RaiseAndSetIfChanged(ref _size, value);
    }
}
```

I am using a custom control as the editor, which just uses two DoubleUpDowns for the width and height and manually updates the bound property:

**ElementSizeEditor.xaml**

```
<UserControl x:Class="MyProject.Controls.ElementSizeEditor"
         xmlns="http://schemas.microsoft.com/winfx/2006/xaml/presentation"
         xmlns:x="http://schemas.microsoft.com/winfx/2006/xaml"
         xmlns:xctk="http://schemas.xceed.com/wpf/xaml/toolkit">
<Grid>
    <StackPanel Grid.Row="0" VerticalAlignment="Stretch" HorizontalAlignment="Left" Orientation="Horizontal">
        <xctk:DoubleUpDown Width="75" TextAlignment="Right" VerticalContentAlignment="Center" 
                           Name="WidthEntry" AllowTextInput="True"
                           ShowButtonSpinner="False" FormatString="0.###" />
        <TextBlock Text="&quot; x " />
        <xctk:DoubleUpDown Width="75" TextAlignment="Right" VerticalContentAlignment="Center" 
                           Name="HeightEntry" AllowTextInput="True" 
                           ShowButtonSpinner="False" FormatString="0.###" />
        <TextBlock Text="&quot;" />
    </StackPanel>
</Grid>
</UserControl>
```

**ElementSizeEditor.xaml.cs**

```
public partial class ElementSizeEditor : UserControl
{
    public static readonly DependencyProperty ValueProperty = 
        DependencyProperty.Register("Value", 
            typeof(Size), 
            typeof(ElementSizeEditor),
            new PropertyMetadata(ValueChanged));

    // manually set the values on the width and height editors when we have a new Size
    private static void ValueChanged(DependencyObject d, DependencyPropertyChangedEventArgs args)
    {
        Size size = (Size)args.NewValue;
        ElementSizeEditor editor = (ElementSizeEditor)d;
        editor.WidthEntry.Value = size.Width;
        editor.HeightEntry.Value = size.Height;
    }

    public Size Value
    {
        get { return (Size)GetValue(ValueProperty); }
        set { SetValue(ValueProperty, value); }
    }

    public ElementSizeEditor()
    {
        InitializeComponent();

        WidthEntry.ValueChanged += ValueChangedHandler;
        HeightEntry.ValueChanged += ValueChangedHandler;
    }

    // manually listen to value changes because we provide a new Size instance for new values
    private void ValueChangedHandler(object sender, RoutedPropertyChangedEventArgs<object> e)
    {
        if (WidthEntry.Value.HasValue && HeightEntry.Value.HasValue &&
            (!Core.Util.Math.AreEquivalent((float)WidthEntry.Value, Value.Width) ||
             !Core.Util.Math.AreEquivalent((float)HeightEntry.Value, Value.Height)))
            Value = new Size((float)WidthEntry.Value.Value, (float)HeightEntry.Value.Value);
    }
}
```

I register the ElementSizeEditor as an app-wide static resource:

**App.xaml**

```
<Application.Resources>
    <DataTemplate x:Key="ElementSizeEditor">
        <controls:ElementSizeEditor Value="{Binding Path=Value}"/>
    </DataTemplate>
</Application.Resources>
```

And make use of it in my properties view:

**ElementPropertiesView.xaml**

```
<UserControl x:Class="MyProject.Views.ElementPropertiesView"
         xmlns="http://schemas.microsoft.com/winfx/2006/xaml/presentation"
         xmlns:x="http://schemas.microsoft.com/winfx/2006/xaml"
         xmlns:xctk="http://schemas.xceed.com/wpf/xaml/toolkit">
<Grid>
    <xctk:PropertyGrid SelectedObject="{Binding}" SelectedObjectName="" SelectedObjectTypeName="{Binding Path=Name}" Grid.Row="0" AutoGenerateProperties="False"
                       ShowAdvancedOptions="False" ShowSortOptions="False" ShowSearchBox="False">
        <xctk:PropertyGrid.EditorDefinitions>
            <xctk:EditorTemplateDefinition TargetProperties="Size" EditingTemplate="{StaticResource ElementSizeEditor}" />
        </xctk:PropertyGrid.EditorDefinitions>
        <xctk:PropertyGrid.PropertyDefinitions>
            <xctk:PropertyDefinition TargetProperties="Size" DisplayName="Size" Description="The Element's size" />
        </xctk:PropertyGrid.PropertyDefinitions>
    </xctk:PropertyGrid>
</Grid>
</UserControl>
```

which is bound appropriately in the code-behind:

**ElementPropertiesView.xaml.cs**

```
public partial class ElementPropertiesView : UserControl, IViewFor<ElementViewModel>
{
    public static readonly DependencyProperty ViewModelProperty = DependencyProperty.Register("ViewModel",
        typeof(ElementViewModel),
        typeof(ElementPropertiesView));

    public ElementPropertiesView()
    {
        InitializeComponent();
        this.WhenActivated(d =>
        {
            d(this.WhenAnyValue(_ => _.ViewModel).BindTo(this, _ => _.DataContext));
        });
    }

    object IViewFor.ViewModel
    {
        get { return ViewModel; }
        set { ViewModel = (ColorElementViewModel)value; }
    }

    public ElementViewModel ViewModel
    {
        get { return (ColorElementViewModel) GetValue(ViewModelProperty); }
        set
        {
            SetValue(ViewModelProperty, value);
        }
    }
}
```

When I load up the properties view, it correctly binds the ElementViewModel to the PropertyGrid's `SelectedObject`, correctly displays the ElementSizeEditor for the Size property, correctly binds to the Value in ElementSizeEditor, and updates the ValueProperty correctly when the user enters new values.

What it doesn't do is feed the new Size value back into the ElementViewModel, and I'm stumped as to why. I've gotten around this in other cases by writing a helper class that gets exposed instead and knows how to reach into the ElementViewModel to update the associated property, but those instances made more sense because there was additional functionality needed. This time I just want to update the ViewModel with a new Size.

Answer (score 0):

That's most probably because you should set binding mode on your DataTemplate to TwoWay. That is to say, in App.xaml, you should change <controls:ElementSizeEditor Value="{Binding Path=Value}"/> to <controls:ElementSizeEditor Value="{Binding Path=Value, **Mode=TwoWay**}"/>